# What do lizardfolk villages look like?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lore, world-building, lizardfolk

I'm working on a D&D 5e campaign's setting that includes a lizardfolk village in a relatively central location, in or near a deep jungle city ruled by dragonborn. Based on previous D&D resources, what does a typical lizardfolk village look like?

Comment: What aspect(s) are you interested on?

Comment: IIRC there's a lizardfolk village in one of the adventures in Ghosts of Saltmarsh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Forgotten Realms wiki entry on lizardfolk](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Lizardfolk#Tribal_Structure) states:

> ### Tribal Structure
>
> Lizardfolk gathered into tribes. A typical tribe might have 150
> lizardfolk, with around 50 male, 50 female, and 50 hatchlings, Another
> might have only 30–60 adults, with half as many hatchlings and one
> tenth that number in unhatched eggs.
>
> Lizardfolk society was patriarchal and leaders held their positions
> for their strength and power alone. Although challenges for leadership
> were rarely made, anyone in the tribe could try and seize power from
> the leader. This would leave the tribe unorganized and vulnerable
> until a new leader took charge or the old leader had reasserted their
> position. Lizardfolk leaders were most often barbarians or even
> druids. In a tribe, they would be assisted by two lieutenants. Many
> skilled warriors were fighters and barbarians.
>
> Tribal shamans, meanwhile, were usually clerics who worshiped
> Semuanya. Shamans rarely served as leaders, and by-and-large only
> offered advice.
>
> Females in the tribes were responsible for hatching eggs, raising
> young, and maintaining the camp. All the females in the tribe would
> work together to raise the young. They monitored their hatchlings
> closely, as the young were difficult to handle and tended to wander
> off, away from camp and into the wilderness.

From general gameplay, I've known lizardfolk villages to be very coastal in nature, they live in longhouses decorated in sea creatures, shells, bone, and even dragons. But that's about as much as I know and I can't source this info. I just know I remember it from playing in an official module so it should be accurate I'd hope.

Comment: But what does a village look like? I can imagine many different concepts that would fit this social structure, but do they live in large longhouses which fit the whole tribe, or mud huts with just a few individuals? Or something else?

Comment: Can those downvoting please leave a reason for the downvote in the comments? This answer seems acceptable for "What does a typical lizardfolk village look like" as it gives a source and a gist of what the general flavour of a lizardfolk environment would be.

Comment: "Forgotten Realms" isn't a source; I assume what Chaosweapon actually means is [the Forgotten Realms wiki page on Lizardfolk](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Lizardfolk), which itself sources the 2003 Races of Faerun book and the 3.5e Monster Manual.

Comment: @mattdm just like for human settlements this will depend a lot on the local environment, consider humans who live in mud huts, skin and bone tents, bamboo stilt houses, wood long houses depending on the local conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If they're a hunter-based society lead by a hunter/warrior patriarch, the village is probably at least lightly fortified and/or in a defensible position, like on a hill or by a lake or river.  There would likely be a circular palisade of small and medium-sized tree trunks or large stones as a defensive perimeter.  One entrance would be enough, and more than that would suggest some advanced tactical aid in the past.

The interior would probably center around a stone structure, which would serve as a temple and shelter for the hatchlings.  The stone would soak up the sunlight and be a place of warmth for the elderly.  The structure itself could be a simple one-room, rough-hewn den or could have multiple rooms with well crafted carved walls, depending on the tribe's age and prosperity.  The structure would likely be fairly low and possibly even be slightly sunken, but probably not subterranean as that would make it somewhat cold.

Two other areas would vie for the next level of priority: a cooking area (for food) and a spring, pond or river (for water).  Food preparation would likely be limited to roasting and grilling meat, with any abundance being smoked to preserve it.  Lizardfolk don't go for much in terms of vegetables, but some simple herbs might be processed here for medicinal or seasoning purposes.  It would be a defined area with open-air cooking and some tools and utensils stored in woven baskets.

After that, there would likely be individual shelters for small families or powerful individuals.  They would be simple, mostly just protection from wind, night rains and some modicum of privacy.  They would range from small lean-tos made of branches and large leaves to larger, fenced areas with multiple rooms and some roofing.

After that, it would depend on the tribe.  Some might have a fenced area for small livestock like chickens.  Others might produce something to trade with other settlements and need a place to store it between shipments.

They would utilize ruins, caves and other pre-existing structures but probably wouldn't do any major construction.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you cite/reference some sources to support your answer?